# Can you use split-function recursively on an split-item in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am struggling with the split function in VBA. Maybe I did something wrong with the declarations despite trying to switch around with `Dim as Variant` and `Dim as String`.

My code looks as following:

```
'Split the txtString variable at every "|" and add every split string item to an array split_sText
Dim txtString as String
.
.
.
Dim split_sText() As String
split_sText() = Split(txtString, "|")

Pick the first part of respective item out of that array and place it at the right cell
Sheets(Table1).Cells(1, 1) = Split(split_sText(15), "_")'
```

split_sText(15) looks like this: "ABC_1234". Of that string I only want to get the "ABC".

The error occurs at the last line because of "runtime error 13 not matching types", which is strange, since I've declared the variables as strings.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The result of `Split(split_sText(15), "_")` will be an array of 2 elements. If you want just the `ABC` portion, try maybe `Sheets(Table1).Cells(1, 1) = Split(split_sText(15), "_")(0)`

Comment: That is indeed a very good point. I tried your idea, but unfortunately it doesnt work. Replacing the `split_sText(15)` with a string `"abc_1234"` still triggers the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> split_sText(15) looks like this: "ABC_1234". Of that string I only want to get the "ABC".

If there's one under score then there'd be a two item array, and you can only assign one array item to a cell:

```
Dim split_sText() As String
split_sText() = Split(txtString, "|")

Dim split_sTextNested() As String
split_sTextNested = Split(split_sText(15), "_")

Sheets(Table1).Cells(1, 1) = split_sTextNested(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking at the wrong place for your error.

`Sheets(Table1)` is the source of the error.

The *Index* argument for the `Sheets` object needs to be either a number, or a sheet name.  Most likely, `Table1` is the `CodeName`.  The `CodeName` of an object returns the actual object.

So if `Table1` is the CodeName, then change to

```
Table1.Cells(1,1) = ...
```

If `Table1` happened to be the worksheet name, then it would be

```
Sheets("Table1").Cells(1,1) = ...
```

If you look at the Project Explorer window in the VBE, under the Microsoft Excel Objects for your project you will see one or more worksheet objects. The `CodeName` is the first name of the worksheet; the worksheet `Name` is the name in parentheses.

There are other issues with how you are splitting the string, but your code should work with a proper `Sheets` reference.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim Sp() As String` declares an array of string type with an undefined number of elements.

`Sp = Split("a_b_c_", "_")` assigns an array to the variable already declared, defining also the number of elements, 0-based.

`Debug.Print Sp(2)` prints the 3rd element to the Immediate Pane.

`Cells(1, 1).Value = Sp(2)` assigns the same value to a cell.

The `Split` function returns an array of string type. However, the following will also work.

```
Dim Sp As Variant
Sp = Split("a_b_c_", "_")
Cells(1, 1).Value = Sp(2)
```

Observe that the variant is *not* declared as an array because the variant c an be anything by nature. `Dim Sp() As Variant` will cause `Sp = Split("a_b_c_", "_")` to fail.

As one final twist, you can also avoid the use of `Sp` with the code below.

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = Split("a_b_c_", "_")(2)
```